# Принуждение к реализации в производных классах

Tags: c#

Допустим, я пишу класс с реализацией десятка методов, но один из методов должен быть реализован пользователем моего класса. Иными словами мне надо принудить наследника к реализации определеного метода, в противном случае мой класс не должен работать.
Как такое воплотить на языке C#?
Мне сказали, что надо использовать интерфейсы, но с ними "не выходит каменный цветок".

Comment: "мой класс не должен работать" -  наследник не должен работать?

Comment: @Igor Мой класс - это базовый класс, а наследник не мой.

Comment: @Igor если хотите ответить на вопрос - напишите ответ. ответы-ссылки в комментариях - зло.

Comment: абстрактные методы - так нормально?

Comment: @Igor ответы-не ссылки в комментариях - тоже зло. пишите развернутый ответ, если хотите ответить. не ограничивайтесь наводящим комментарием :)

Answer (score 3):

Пометьте класс и метод, который обязателен к реализации, как абстрактные:

```
abstract class Base
{
    // обязателен к реализации в не-абстрактных наследниках
    protected abstract void SomeMethod();

    // не обязателен к переопределению в наследнике
    protected virtual void SomeNonAbstractMethod()
    {

    }
}

// не-абстрактный наследник
class Child : Base
{
    // если метод не реализован - компилятор выдаст ошибку
    protected override void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `private override`? - интересно

Comment: @Igor студия допечатала :) подправил.

Comment: второй метод и не должен реализовывать наследник. Либо он должен быть еще и `virtual`, тогда может быть реализован, но не обязательно

Comment: про `new` я в курсе, но это на крайний случай, вроде как когда нельзя, но очень хочется.

Comment: @rdorn добавил virtual. но вообще идея была в том, чтобы показать что в абстрактных классах могут быть не-абстрактные методы